# malloc, allocating a matrix

Tags: c, pointers

I allocate a vector of strings in this way:

```
    int number =0;
    char** matrix = (char**)malloc(10);
    //when I have to allocate a string, use 
    matrix[number] = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_string);
    number++; //MAX 10
```

Ok, I want that the vector has a null pointer when there's no string, so I can use calloc:

```
    int number =0;
    char** matrix = (char**)calloc(10,1);
    //when I have to allocate a string, use 
    matrix[number] = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_string);
    number++; //MAX 10
```

But, if I do not want to use calloc, and use malloc instead, inizializing all the pointer values to null, why I get a SIGABRT signal on linux?

```
    nt number =0;
    char** matrix = (char**)malloc(10);
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        matrix[i] = NULL;
    //when I have to allocate a string, use 
    matrix[number] = (char*)malloc(lenght_of_string);    //ERROR: SIGABRT
    number++; //MAX 10
```

I think that in the for cicle I overwrite some special informations about the memory allocated, can someone explain me what it happen?

---

Thank you anishsane, you are right, but sometimes I don't respect rules. So bad...anyway, sizeof(char) returns 1, so in this example it's the same to write 10*sizeof(char) and only 10.
Why in the calloc function you pass first the size of char and then the number of chars? I read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/ and I should pass first the number of chars and then the sizeof

Comment: `sizeof(char**) != sizeof(char)`

Comment: Pointer is 4 bytes of memory. `(char**)malloc(10)` tries to allocate _2.5_ `char*` positions!

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, it's 4 bytes on a 32 bit architecture. As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't make assumptions on the size of pointers unless you write overly platform specific code. That's what `sizeof` is for.

Answer (score 9):

```
char** matrix = (char**)malloc(10);
```

Should be

```
char** matrix = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
```

Also,

```
char** matrix = (char**)calloc(10,1);
```

Should have been

```
char** matrix = (char**)calloc(sizeof(char*),10);
```

Comment: And then you should handle the failure case: `if (matrix == NULL) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};`

Comment: There is no need to cast `mallic/calloc/realloc` in C.

Comment: And a comment, that `calloc` for initializing assumes pointers with all bytes set to 0 to be null pointers.

Comment: @alk: Yes, that's right. I just preferred to point only the fatal error here. But yes, your comment is absolutely correct.